# Conditionally displaying form elements

Tags: angularjs

Building a website where user can browse trough list of stored procedures and can select it, set parameters. Then the returned data will display in the form of the chart or table. So I'm half way through, but now straggling with the idea how to display form inputs for the parameters. So I'm returning the list of parameters with the types for the selected stored procedure.

```
{  
   "DataSourceId":"21",
   "Params":[  
      {  
         "Id":"1",
         "Name":"DateFrom",
         "TypeId":"3"
      },
      {  
         "Id":"2",
         "Name":"DateTo",
         "TypeId":"3"
      },
      {  
         "Id":"3",
         "Name":"LineID",
         "TypeId":"1"
      },
      {  
         "Id":"4",
         "Name":"MachineID",
         "TypeId":"2"
      }
   ]
}
```

How do I conditionally displays the form input element (date picker, option select, etc). ng-required or ng-show will not work as I never know how many of parameters I will have. A custom directive? Don't really know where to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `ng-repeat` with a nested [`ng-switch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch). Then use `ng-switch-when` to change the behaviour, depending on the field you used at `ng-switch`.

```
<span ng-repeat="param in Params">
    <span ng-switch on="param.TypeId">
        <div ng-switch-when="1"> <!-- your type 1 form --></div>
        <div ng-switch-when="2"> <!-- your type 2 form --></div>
        <div ng-switch-when="3"> <!-- your type 3 form --></div>
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Wow,so simple! It may actually works, will try this tomorrow morning. Thanks

Comment: Works perfect, Thank you :)